# How to run a website having different pages for different Country on single domain name in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, localization, globalization

How to make website having different pages for different country in asp.net ? 
Should I add foldar for each country or dynamic content using C#. I dont want to use different domain name.

Comment: What code are you already having ? We don't write complete code for you.

Comment: Currently there is no feature of localization. All pages are in single foldar.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need different domain for languages. 
ASP.NET has feature called resources you can use this.
For more detail on how to use it. please refer to. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427(v=vs.140).aspx